# Can I raise both sides of an equation to a variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have the function:
$$y^x = x^y$$

Can I raise both sides to the power of $\frac1x$, yielding:

$$x^{y^{\frac1x}}=x^{\frac y x}=y$$

Comment: In general, you can apply any strictly monotonic function to both sides of an equation. $f(y) = y^{1/x}$ is a monotonic function as long as $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Power of one term get reciprocal in power of term on other side.